# Custom Listener in Service Fabric + How to access from client?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Actually I am trying to learn Service fabric and its custom listener part. For this I have created a sample Service Fabric Stateful service which does nothing but returning a number 10 here.

```
internal sealed class StatefulService1 : StatefulService, INumber
{

    protected override IEnumerable<ServiceReplicaListener> 
    CreateServiceReplicaListeners()
    {
        return new[] { new ServiceReplicaListener(context => new 
        HttpCommunicationListener(context), "HttpListener") };
    }

    public int GetNumber()
    {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

I have created a custom Listener for this as below:

```
class HttpCommunicationListener : ICommunicationListener
{
    StatefulServiceContext serviceContext;

    string publishAddress;

    public HttpCommunicationListener(StatefulServiceContext 
 serviceContext)
    {
        this.serviceContext = serviceContext;
    }

    public void Abort()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task CloseAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<string> OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var codePackageContext = 
 this.serviceContext.CodePackageActivationContext;
 EndpointResourceDescription desc =  
 codePackageContext.GetEndpoint("ServiceEndpoint");

        var port = desc.Port;

        var address = string.Format("http://Address:{0}/", port);
        this.publishAddress = address.Replace("Address", 
    FabricRuntime.GetNodeContext().IPAddressOrFQDN);

        return Task.FromResult(publishAddress);
    }
}
```

On the client side, I am struggling to access the GetNumber method using my listener, 
My Client Side Implementation:

```
class CustomCommunicationClient : ICommunicationClient
{
    public CustomCommunicationClient(ResolvedServicePartition partition)
    {
        this.ResolvedServicePartition = partition;
        // this.Endpoint = partition.GetEndpoint();
    }

    public ResolvedServicePartition ResolvedServicePartition { get; set; }

    public string ListenerName { get; set; }

    public ResolvedServiceEndpoint Endpoint { get; set; }
}
```

Client Factory impl:

```
class CustomCommunicationClientFactory : CommunicationClientFactoryBase<CustomCommunicationClient>
{
    ResolvedServicePartition partition;

    public CustomCommunicationClientFactory(ResolvedServicePartition partition)
    {
        this.partition = partition;
    }

    protected override void AbortClient(CustomCommunicationClient client)
    {
    }

    protected override Task<CustomCommunicationClient> CreateClientAsync(string endpoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new CustomCommunicationClient(this.partition));
    }

    protected override bool ValidateClient(CustomCommunicationClient client)
    {
        return true;
    }

    protected override bool ValidateClient(string endpoint, CustomCommunicationClient client)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Main.cs

```
class Program
{
    private static string ServiceName = "fabric:/CustomCommunication.StatefulService/StatefulService1";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var servicePartition = GetServicePartitionAsync();
        var clientFactory = new CustomCommunicationClientFactory(servicePartition.Result);

        var partition = new ServicePartitionKey(1);
        var myServicePartitionClient = new ServicePartitionClient<CustomCommunicationClient>(clientFactory,
                                       new Uri(ServiceName), partition);
        Console.WriteLine("Running request client...");

        //var result =
        //    myServicePartitionClient.InvokeWithRetryAsync(client => client., CancellationToken.None).Result;

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static Task<ResolvedServicePartition> GetServicePartitionAsync()
    {
        ServicePartitionResolver resolver = ServicePartitionResolver.GetDefault();

        Task<ResolvedServicePartition> partition = resolver.ResolveAsync(new Uri(ServiceName), 
                                             new ServicePartitionKey(1), CancellationToken.None);

        return partition;
    }
}
```

Can someone please guide me on how to do it? It would be great if someone provide me a code for this.

Comment: did you see this: https://dzimchuk.net/implementing-a-rest-client-for-internal-communication-in-service-fabric/ ?

Comment: Thanks for replying @LoekD. I want to know how the custom http listener works with service fabric and how client will access the functionality exposed by service. Please put some light on this.

Comment: Have a look at this example: https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.ServiceBus/blob/master/ServiceFabric.ServiceBus.Clients/ServiceBusTopicCommunicationClient.cs it shows an implementation that calls service bus, but you can change it to use an HttpClient to call your API.  You could deserialize the returned JSON into an object there.